# Jquery confirm disables masked input in chrome v 44

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, maskedinput

While using google chrome stable version 44.0.2403.107 with Jquery masked input. After Jquery confirm is fired the masked input is disabled. This didnot occur in google chrome version 43. 
Here is the link to jsfiddle 
 http://jsfiddle.net/hkaqs2s4/

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999?9-9999");
var map = [ '£11.99', '£13.99', '£14.99' ];

$('#payslips-required').change(function(){
    var o = parseInt($(this).val()) < 3 ? $(this).val()-1 : 2;
    $('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
    confirm("Alert here");
});
```

Basically , if I choose a value from dropdown and after the confirm box is fired, the masking on textbox with id phone is lost. 
Please advise on how to maintain the masking on the text box after the confirm is triggered.

Comment: i cannot replicate issue on chrome v44.0.2403.107 m win7

Comment: I am using windows 8.1

Comment: On FF the mask disappears as soon as the first input field loses focus.
The CDN hosted jquery.maskedinput version is [outdated](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) and no longer maintained..